# SUSE Linux 12sp2 server struct at maintenance mode how to troubleshoot this issue?

Tags: bugs

We have changed some OS related parameters on SUSE linux server after that we have taken server reboot in this time server went to maintenance mode.. Please help me out in this situation..

Answer (score 0):

If the server is in maintenance mode:

1. login with root password
2. Go to `/etc/fstab`, comment nfs and all local FS(except root FS) then save and exit(:wq!)
3. reboot the server --> reboot
4. once the server is up, then uncomment the commented FS in /ets/fstab.
5. `mount -a`